# Proper Handling of Version Numbers Between Git Branches

Tags: nuget, versioning, myget

We have an assembly that we push to myget as a nuget package. We then reference the assembly in another project. At this point, everything works great.

Now, suppose we swap to our master branch in git and need to fix a bug. When we do a publish to myget, the package version is later.

When doing merges between branches, it's not obvious which version is the right one since we can't rely on newer versions being the proper one for that branch.

Is there a standardized way of versioning that takes care of this situation? I'm sure this is very  common but I'm not sure the proper approach to take?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could look into using GitVersion.exe for that - https://github.com/ParticularLabs/GitVersion